# Twilio incoming sms not working in Zoho CRM

Tags: twilio, zoho, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I have integrated TwilioSMSExtension in Zoho CRM and setup the programmable sms service in Twilio.

When I send the new sms from zoho crm contact module that's working fine. But incoming messages not received in contact module. I have attached screenshots of zoho and Twilio issue and open the below 3 URLs.

tinyurl.com/ybdwp59u

tinyurl.com/y7gdrhyc

tinyurl.com/y8eq755s

Answer (score 0):

Twilio wont send the incoming message anywhere unless you check:

[image]

And Zoho provides some URL to populate the webhook.

Comment: Can share the tutorial of how to integrate incoming call in Zoho CRM OR zoho URL which I populate the webhook.

Comment: You should contact Zoho's technical support on the Twilio integration, since it is specific to their application.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs you shared show that you were using an old version of the Twilio SMS extension for Zoho CRM. The latest version (https://marketplace.zoho.com/crm/twilio-sms-extension-for-zoho-crm) automatically updates webhook URLs so this issue shouldn't be a problem anymore.